# java 8 - ZonedDateTime not equal another ZonedDateTime

Tags: java, java-8, java-time

I created two ZonedDateTime objects and I think they are should be equal:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ZoneId zid = ZoneId.of("America/New_York");
    ZoneOffset offset = ZoneOffset.from(LocalDateTime.now().atZone(zid));
    ZonedDateTime zdt0 = ZonedDateTime.of(2014, 8, 24, 21, 10, 1, 777000002, offset);
    ZonedDateTime zdt1 = ZonedDateTime.of(2014, 8, 24, 21, 10, 1, 777000002, zid);
    boolean equals = Objects.equals(zdt0, zdt1);
    System.out.println("equals: " + equals);
}
```

In debugger I see that class of member of ZonedDateTime **zone** in first case is **java.time.ZoneOffset** and in second java.time.ZoneRegion and this is makes ZonedDateTime objects not equal. This is  confusing...
Any ideas?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You are checking for object equality which evaluates to `false` as these objects are not equivalent. One is bound to a `ZoneId`, the other to a `ZoneOffset`. If you want to check whether they represent the same time, you can use the not very intuitively named method `isEqual`.

E.g.:

```
ZoneId zid = ZoneId.of("America/New_York");
ZoneOffset offset = ZoneOffset.from(LocalDateTime.now().atZone(zid));
ZonedDateTime zdt0 = ZonedDateTime.of(2014, 8, 24, 21, 10, 1, 777000002, offset);
ZonedDateTime zdt1 = ZonedDateTime.of(2014, 8, 24, 21, 10, 1, 777000002, zid);
System.out.println("isEqual:" + zdt0.isEqual(zdt1));
System.out.println("equals: " + zdt0.equals(zdt1));
```

prints:

```
isEqual:true
equals: false
```

Btw, note that you don’t need to use `Objects.equals(a,b)` for two objects you already know to be non-`null`. You can invoke `a.equals(b)` directly.

Comment: Thank you! This is helpful and you are right: isEqual is not not very intuitive...

Answer (score 8):

This played hell on me for hours too when using Jackson to serialize / deserialize instances of ZonedDateTime and then compare them against each other for equality to verify that my code was working correctly. I don't fully understand the implications but all I've learned is to use isEqual instead of equals. But this throws a big wrench in testing plans as most assertion utilities will just call the standard .equals().

Here's what I finally came up with after struggling for quite some time:

```
@Test
public void zonedDateTimeCorrectlyRestoresItself() {

    // construct a new instance of ZonedDateTime
    ZonedDateTime now = ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("Z"));
    // offset = {ZoneOffset@3820} "Z"
    // zone   = {ZoneOffset@3820} "Z"

    String starting = now.toString();

    // restore an instance of ZonedDateTime from String
    ZonedDateTime restored = ZonedDateTime.parse(starting);
    // offset = {ZoneOffset@3820} "Z"
    // zone   = {ZoneOffset@3820} "Z"

    assertThat(now).isEqualTo(restored); // ALWAYS succeeds

    System.out.println("test");
}

@Test
public void jacksonIncorrectlyRestoresZonedDateTime() throws Exception {

    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    objectMapper.findAndRegisterModules();

    // construct a new instance of ZonedDateTime
    ZonedDateTime now = ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("Z"));
    // offset = {ZoneOffset@3820} "Z"
    // zone   = {ZoneOffset@3820} "Z"


    String converted = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(now);

    // restore an instance of ZonedDateTime from String
    ZonedDateTime restored = objectMapper.readValue(converted, ZonedDateTime.class);
    // offset = {ZoneOffset@3820} "Z"
    // zone   = {ZoneOffset@3821} "UTC"

    assertThat(now).isEqualTo(restored); // NEVER succeeds

    System.out.println("break point me");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The `equals()` method on `ZonedDateTime` requires that all component parts of the object are equal. Since a `ZoneOffset` is not equal to a `ZoneRegion` (even though both are subclasses of `ZoneId`), the method returns false. Read about [VALJOs](http://blog.joda.org/2014/03/valjos-value-java-objects.html) to understand more as to why value types are compared in this way.

The `isEqual` method only compares the instant on the time-line, which may or may not be what you want. You can also use the `timeLineOrder()` [method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/chrono/ChronoZonedDateTime.html#timeLineOrder--) to compare two `ZoneDateTime` only using the time-line.

Answer (score 1):

This caused us pain for a while too. The `ZonedDateTime` values actually represent **identical** times, however their zone "types" are different, which is why they are not equal.

The above answers are correct, however I thought I'd add a visual that might further help:

[image]

In the `ZonedDateTime` code, we find, which shows the zone comparison:

[image]